# Access token for API controller inside Identity server itself

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, thinktecture-ident-server

I have created an identity server 4 project and a mvc client project. Authentication flow works as expected. I have added an API controller in the same project as identity server and i want to hit this api resource from mvc client.Essentially,i need both identity server middleware and token validation middle inside the idenity server project.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use ID4 as both authentication server and token server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already, add these Nuget packages to your already established IdentityServer app/site:

```
IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
```

Add another Api Resource to your resources list:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
{
    return new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api1", "My API"), 
        new ApiResource("api2", "IdentityServer API")
    };
}
```

Update your client configuration to allow api2:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",

            ... omitted

            AllowedScopes = new List<string>
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                "api2"
            }
        }
    };
}
```

In the IdentityServer's Configure method in Startup add:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "api2"
});
```

Comment: I have done something similar. It turns out tht i was goofing up with audience in access token :( . It's working now. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you add your consuming code to this example from the client. That is the part I am not understanding?